Cannot Accces to Grpc with subdirectory from Postman
I have a simple grpc server with simple configuration
builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(serverOptions =>
{
    serverOptions.ListenAnyIP(80, listenOptions => listenOptions.Protocols = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.HttpProtocols.Http1AndHttp2);
    serverOptions.ListenAnyIP(5000, listenOptions => listenOptions.Protocols = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.HttpProtocols.Http2);
});
builder.Services.AddGrpc();
app.MapGrpcService<SMSServiceGrpcService>();

The problem is that on our production stage the path to this server looks like this
https://dev.tech/sms-async.SendMessage

Now from following code i can access it, and everything working fine:
var handler = new SubdirectoryHandler(new HttpClientHandler(), "/sms-async.SendMessage"); 
var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);
    
var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("https://dev.tech",
   new GrpcChannelOptions { HttpClient = httpClient }); 
var client = new SendMessage.SendMessageClient(channel);
    
var request = new SendSmsRequest {
    Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
    PhoneNumber = "+8934834",
    Provider = (Provider)1,
    Process = "exampleProcess",
    SmsText = "Hello from gRPC!" };
    
    var response = await client.SendSmsAsync(request);

The problem is there is no way i can access to this grpc server neither from postman or bloom rpc, i understand the problem is that i have subdirectory in a path dev.tech/sms-async.SendMessage because when im ran localy i could access to localhost:5000, so anyone can tell how configure postman or bloomRpc so i can access this address

I assume the subdirectory in your path (sms-async) isn't a protobuf Service reference? gRPC uses the path to represent protobuf package.Service/Method and your implementation is inconsistent with that. If you can (to avoid this type of issue), you should consider rooting your gRPC Services at the host.

i cannot, it`s something that came above me, this is how my proto file looks like syntax = "proto3";
option csharp_namespace = "SMSAsyncGrpcService";
package sms_async;
service SendMessage{
rpc SendSms(SendSmsRequest) returns (SendSmsResponse);
}

It's a little unclear and I'm on a phone but your host can be dev.tech and your fully-qualified path should be sms_async.SendMessage.SendSms (the _ may get replaced with a -). I think you can't remap that path.

after debugging i saw my actual url that i pointing to is
https://dev.tech/sms-async.SendMessage/sms_async.SendMessage/SendSms.
How i can access it through rpcBloom or postman?
